# How to externally access MobilePush subscription details

Tags: mobilepush

I'd like to know if there is a way of pulling subscription status information for MobilePush, by contact key, in the same way you can using various API calls for both the ExactTarget and MobileConnect products?

I've pulled all the data extensions for the business unit but don't see anything obviously related to push nor does the SFMC documentation offer much.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let me address your question with a bit of background that I think will help frame your question in an easier-to-answer way.

MobilePush, MobileConnect and Email contacts are all contacts. Because they're all contacts, their information is available via the contacts api, rather than say, the mobilePush API endpoints.

I believe what you're looking for is documented here: (Though I admit this isn't intuitive.)  https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/contacts/fetchAttributes.html

I've taken the liberty of translating the json example they give into something thats more focused on mobilePush. The request attributes array is the list of attributes from the contact you'd like returned. Conditions, is an array of, well, conditions that must be met in order for that contact's information to be returned.

```
{
"request": {
    "attributes": [{
            "key": "MobilePush Demographics.First Name"
        },
        {
            "key": "MobilePush Demographics.Last Name"
        }]

},
"conditionSet": {
    "operator": "And",
    "conditionSets": [],
    "conditions": [{
        "attribute": {
            "key": "MobilePush Demographics.First Name"
        },
        "operator": "Equals",
        "value": {
            "items": ["Kevin"]
        }
    }]
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your input Kevin but this is returning attributes and I believe the data I am after sits under "Membership"